# Assets repository

Tags: version-control, assets, repository

I use mercurial as my main scm tool. Before I've worked with svn and others but all of these repositories are designed specificaly to work with plain text code.
My assets and documents are binaries and usually are big files (10~50 MB each) and my problem is not about keep track of what has changed exactly, but  I want at least the basic functionality that scm's give me for code: tracking what files have changed (who,when,comments...), historical backup and distributed sync.

What tools do you use for this and how do you link changes in assets with changes in code if you are using different repository kinds?